# How do I do modulus in C++?

Tags: c++, integer, modulo

How do I perform a mod operation between two integers in C++?

Comment: Is there a term for a post where googling the title yields the answer?

Comment: And.. click here if you don't mind stackoverflow being the ultimate resource, even for easy questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:
x=y%z

Comment: Except that the result is negative for a negative dividend.

Comment: @Potatocorn maybe, maybe not. That's implementation-defined.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: 5.6/4: "(a/b)*b + a%b is equal to a", so round-toward-zero (the overwhelmingly popular implementation, for better or worse) implies that, and it is mandated by C++0x.

Comment: Round towards zero is mandated by c++0x, but *not* c++03.  In both standards, your formula must hold true, but the sign of `a%b` depends on how integral division is implemented.  The sign is well defined as non-negative only if `a` and `b` are both non-negative.

Comment: @Potatocorn Implementation. Defined.

Comment: @Dennis the sign is well-defined as non-negative only if _`a` is non-negative and `b` is positive_  :p

Comment: In any case, it won't map negative integers onto a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic modular arithmetic ring. If it does, you are very lucky and your program is very unportable.

Answer (score 16):

C++ has the `%` operator, occasionally and misleadingly named "the modulus" operator. In particular the STL has the `modulus<>` functor in the `<functional>` header. That's not the mathematical modulus operator, mind you, because in modulus arithmetics `a mod b` by definition evaluates to a non-negative value for any value of `a` and any positive value of `b`. In C++ the sign of the result of `a % b` is *implementation-defined* if either of the arguments is negative. So, we would more appropriately name the `%` operator the *remainder* operator.

That said, if you truly want the mathematical modulus operator then you can define a function to do just that:

```
template<typename V>
V mod(const V& a, const V& b)
{
    return (a % b + b) % b;
}
```

So long as `b` is a positive value a call to the above function will yield a non-negative result.

Comment: No one else mentions how % is essentially a remainder operator in C++, and fail to provide a modulus implementation that wraps around properly given a negative input value for a.  This is the best answer.

Comment: This is the only correct answer. If you want remainder, not modulo, use %

Answer (score 14):

In c++, use % operator

[More Help](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html)

Answer (score 10):

As the other answers have stated, you can use the C++ % operator.  But be aware that there's a wrinkle no one has mentioned yet: in the expression `a % b`, what if  `a` is negative?
Should the result of this operation be positive or negative?  The C++ standard leaves this up to the
implementation.  So if you want to handle negative inputs portably, you should probably
do something like `r = abs(a) % b`, then fix up the sign of `r` to match your requirements.

Comment: That's assuming you want the implied `div` operation to be round-towards-zero.  If you want round-towards-negative-infinity, then you'll want `r = (unsigned(a) + offset * b) % b`, where `offset` is big enough for `a + offset * b` to always be positive.

Answer (score 0):

Using the modulus `%` operator :

```
int modulus_a_b = a % b;
```

Comment: `a` and `b` are integers... so why `double`?  `modulus_a_b` should be the same type as `a` and `b`.

Comment: @Mike: well, `a % b` will be either `int`, or else the same type as at least one of `a` and `b`. So you have a few choices for the type of `modulus_a_b`, depending on context :-)

Comment: @Steve: But only one of those choices is the type that the `%` operator returns.  All the others imply a typecast, er, `static_cast<>`.  `double` is certainly one of the latter.  Also, using `double` means using the slowest math available (unless there's a `long double` type, dog forbid)...

Comment: The reason I said a lot of choice is because for instance the result of `short % short` is an `int`, not a `short`, but depending on context it probably makes more sense to use it as a `short`. So there's a conflict between "the same type as a and b" vs "avoiding an implicit conversion".

Answer (score 0):

if you use double variable, you should use;

```
double x;
double y;
double result = fmod(x, y);
```