# How to code a modulo (%) operator in C/C++/Obj-C that handles negative numbers

Tags: c++, c, c++11, operator-overloading, modulo

One of my pet hates of C-derived languages (as a mathematician)  is that

```
(-1) % 8 // comes out as -1, and not 7

fmodf(-1,8) // fails similarly
```

What's the best solution?

C++ allows the possibility of templates and operator overloading, but both of these are murky waters for me. examples gratefully received.

Comment: I don't think this is quite a "duplicate" of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828092/python-style-integer-division-modulus-in-c under the official definition. It's not true that this question's answers can be merged into that one's, because this question only asks about modulus, not also division. But I think this question is covered by that one, so it's close. My answer is there already, FWIW.

Comment: Maybe that thread should be split, as it asks two separate questions.  the best way to do that might be to re-ask the division question separately and then point it towards that answer.  I will leave it to someone who understands the mechanisms of this website better.

Comment: @Pi owhere is `%` said to be the *modulo*... it's the *remainder*.

Comment: Here's another thread that this is a "duplicate" of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082917/mod-of-negative-number-is-melting-my-brain Just for reference on this `%` problem.

Comment: If you are only dividing powers of two then it might be a better idea to use and: `(-1) & 8 == 7`

Comment: @Henry W. `(-1) & 8 == 7 `???  `(-1) & 8` will only result in 0 or 8, not 7.  Perhaps you meant `(-1) & (8-1)`?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

First of all I'd like to note that you cannot even rely on the fact that `(-1) % 8 == -1`. the only thing you can rely on is that `(x / y) * y + ( x % y) == x`. However whether or not the remainder is negative is *implementation-defined*.

Reference: C++03 paragraph 5.6 clause 4:

> The binary / operator yields the quotient, and the binary % operator yields the remainder from the division of the first expression by the second. If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined; otherwise (a/b)*b + a%b is equal to a. If both operands are nonnegative then the remainder is nonnegative; ***if not, the sign of the remainder is implementation-defined***.

Here it follows a version that handles both negative operands so that the result of the subtraction of the *remainder* from the *divisor* can be subtracted from the *dividend* so it will be *floor* of the actual division. `mod(-1,8)` results in 7, while `mod(13, -8)` is -3.

```
int mod(int a, int b)
{
   if(b < 0) //you can check for b == 0 separately and do what you want
     return -mod(-a, -b);   
   int ret = a % b;
   if(ret < 0)
     ret+=b;
   return ret;
}
```

Comment: I just tested the first chunk and that works,  though I can't get my head around why!   I would hesitate to use it,  as I'm not sure whether it would work for *any* compiler implementation of % that satisfies the criterion of (x / y) * y + ( x % y) == x.  where did you get that from, out of curiosity? Is that in the C standard?  If it is robust,  it may be preferable over my method (below) for integers in terms of speed.

Comment: I am guessing there is a second criterion that |x%y| < |y|.   so the specification for x%y  would go:
x%y (for int x, y) returns an integer r, s.t. (x / y) * y + r == x, and |r| < |y|

Comment: @Ohmu: If you want to cover the second criterion change `if` to `while`. But it's practically unnecessary

Comment: @Armen: The second criterion is what makes `if` work correctly.  But your whole premise is dead wrong: **Integer division is well-defined in the C++ standard as using truncation toward zero, which guarantees that the sign of `x%y` is the same as the sign of `x`**

Comment: @Ohmu: Yes, that's in the C++ standard.  <quote> For
integral operands the / operator yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded; if the quotient a/b is representable in the type of the result, (a/b)*b  +  a%b is equal to a.</quote>

Comment: -1. It's been 11 years since this was implementation defined. ISO 9899:1999 defined it, and unfortunately chose the bad definition.

Comment: @Ben, @R.. C++03 paragraph 5.6 clause 4: < quote > The binary / operator yields the quotient, and the binary % operator yields the remainder from the division of the first expression by the second. If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined; otherwise (a/b)*b + a%b is equal to a. If both operands are nonnegative then the remainder is nonnegative; **if not, the sign of the remainder is implementation-defined**.< end quote> What will you say to this?

Comment: Great information Armen! Would you consider editing the knowledge contained in these comments back into your answer when it stabilises? It's a bit hidden here.

Comment: @Ohmu: Good point, hopefully I'll avoid future downvotes... (got 2 already for this answer)

Comment: You guys are quoting C++ standards.  What's the simplest solution guaranteed to run on any C compiler?  Armen you need to clarify your solution scope.

Comment: @Armen: You conveniently deleted the footnote <quote>... integer division follows the rules defined in the ISO Fortran standard, ISO/IEC 1539:1991, in which the quotient is always rounded toward zero</quote>.  The new C++ standard upgrades this behavior from "preferred" to mandatory, just like Fortran and C.

Comment: @Armen: Also, try explaining the quotient and remainder of (-32768/-1) stored in a 16-bit signed integer type using your quoted specification.  The old spec was broken, the new wording is the only one worth anything.

Comment: @Ben: I never saw the footnote, thanks for the info. But let's say the old spec "could be better", and not "was broken" because implementation-defined makes their wording not contradictive... convenient :)

Comment: @Armen: The old spec is broken, but the brokenness is different from the sign issue, and it's easy to miss until you look at the new wording.  C++03 didn't have "if the quotient a/b is representable in the type of the result", which causes problems for `INT_MIN / -1` (on two's complement implementations).  Under the old spec, `-32768 % -1` might have to evaluate to `-65536` (which also isn't in range of the 16-bit type, yuck!) in order for the identity to hold.

Comment: re "However whether or not the remainder is negative is implementation-defined.", C++11 guarantees that integer division rounds towards 0.

Comment: Note: corner case problems: 1) `mod_rev2(a, INT_MIN)` --> infinite recursion. 2)  `mod_rev2(INT_MIN, some_negative_int)` as `-INT_MIN` may lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: I corrected an error in the code for `b<0` (the previous version computed `mod(-a,-b)` rather than `mod(a,-b)`). I'll leave it up to the OP to decide what to do about `b == INT_MIN`.

Comment: The expression  a % b is undefined when b is not positive. It should be treated like division by zero.

Comment: The old declared wrong answer distracts reading. High quality answers just shows the correct answer, don't append it in edits leaving rotten bits. I will upvote when the answer will be cleaned.

Comment: The deregistered user @user1084944 changed the code to calculate mod(a,-b) in case of b negative without proper explanation. I restored the previous version.

Comment: About the change from @user1084944, I thought more about it: the result of the subtraction of the *remainder*
from the *divisor* can be subtracted from the *dividend* so it will be *floor* of the actual division. Let's take for example: mod(13, -8). If it's `mod(a, -b)` -> 5, 13 - 5 = 8 -> 8/-8 = -1. But -1 is the *ceiling* of 13.0 / -8. If it's `mod(-a, -b)` -> 3, 13 - 3 = 10 -> 10 / -8 it's rational so it can't be.
If we take `-mod(-a, -b)` -> -3, 13 -(-3) = 16 -> 16 / -8 = -2 and -2 is exactly the *floor* of 13.0 / -8 . I am changing the code accordingly.

Comment: Not a proof of correctness but also searching !google "13 mod -8" and the result is -3.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a C function that handles positive OR negative integer OR fractional values for BOTH OPERANDS

```
#include <math.h>
float mod(float a, float N) {return a - N*floor(a/N);} //return in range [0, N)
```

This is surely the most elegant solution from a mathematical standpoint.  However, I'm not sure if it is robust in handling integers.  Sometimes floating point errors creep in when converting int -> fp -> int.

I am using this code for non-int s, and a separate function for int.

NOTE: need to trap N = 0!

Tester code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float mod(float a, float N)
{
    float ret = a - N * floor (a / N);

    printf("%f.1 mod %f.1 = %f.1 \n", a, N, ret);

    return ret;
}

int main (char* argc, char** argv)
{
    printf ("fmodf(-10.2, 2.0) = %f.1  == FAIL! \n\n", fmodf(-10.2, 2.0));

    float x;
    x = mod(10.2f, 2.0f);
    x = mod(10.2f, -2.0f);
    x = mod(-10.2f, 2.0f);
    x = mod(-10.2f, -2.0f);

    return 0;
}
```

(Note: You can compile and run it straight out of CodePad: http://codepad.org/UOgEqAMA)

Output:

> fmodf(-10.2, 2.0) = -0.20  == FAIL!
>
> 10.2 mod 2.0 = 0.2
>   10.2 mod -2.0 = -1.8
>   -10.2 mod 2.0 = 1.8
>   -10.2 mod -2.0 = -0.2

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work with integers. They would need to be converted to floating point before the division to allow you to use `floor()`. Also, you may loose precision when you convert to float: Try `(float)1000000001/3`, you'll be surprised at the results!

Comment: This works well, I was looking for a replacement for ill-advised usages of `fmod()` with negative `a` parameters.

Answer (score 9):

I have just noticed that Bjarne Stroustrup labels `%` as the **remainder** operator, *not* the modulo operator.

I would bet that this is its formal name in the ANSI C & C++ specifications, and that abuse of terminology has crept in.  Does anyone know this for a fact?

But if this is the case then C's fmodf() function (and probably others) are very misleading.   they should be labelled fremf(), etc

Comment: The C11 standard (or the final [public draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) to be exact) mentions "modulo" six times, but only in relation to the representation of various types. Not once does it mention "modulo" in relation to the *remainder* operator (`%`).

Answer (score 9):

The simplest general function to find the positive modulo would be this-
It would work on both positive and negative values of x.

```
int modulo(int x,int N){
    return (x % N + N) %N;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For integers this is simple. Just do

```
(((x < 0) ? ((x % N) + N) : x) % N)
```

where I am supposing that `N` is positive and representable in the type of `x`. Your favorite compiler should be able to optimize this out, such that it ends up in just one mod operation in assembler.

Comment: Doesn't work: for `int x=-9001; unsigned int N=2000;` it gives 2295, not 999.

Comment: @HubertKario Maybe check again? There is no way that something modulo 2000 gives 2295, you must have made a mistake.

Comment: @SamHocevar: I think the problem here is the weird C integer promotion rules. signed promote to unsigned and promoting a negative signed integer value to unsigned invokes undefined behavior in C.

Comment: I believe a much simpler (and more efficient) form would be: `(x < 0) ? (x % N + N) : (x % N)`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a new answer to an old question, based on this [Microsoft Research paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/151917/divmodnote-letter.pdf) and references therein.

Note that from C11 and C++11 onwards, the semantics of `div` has become **truncation towards zero** (see `[expr.mul]/4`). Furthermore, for `D` divided by `d`, C++11 guarantees the following about the quotient `qT` and remainder `rT`

```
auto const qT = D / d;
auto const rT = D % d;
assert(D == d * qT + rT);
assert(abs(rT) < abs(d));
assert(signum(rT) == signum(D) || rT == 0);
```

where `signum` maps to -1, 0, +1, depending on whether its argument is <, ==, > than 0 (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4609795/819272) for source code).

With truncated division, **the sign of the remainder is equal to the sign of the dividend `D`**, i.e. `-1 % 8 == -1`. C++11 also provides a `std::div` function that returns a struct with members `quot` and `rem` according to truncated division.

There are other definitions possible, e.g. so-called **floored division** can be defined in terms of the builtin truncated division

```
auto const I = signum(rT) == -signum(d) ? 1 : 0;
auto const qF = qT - I;
auto const rF = rT + I * d;
assert(D == d * qF + rF);
assert(abs(rF) < abs(d));
assert(signum(rF) == signum(d));
```

With floored division, **the sign of the remainder is equal to the sign of the divisor `d`**. In languages such as Haskell and Oberon, there are builtin operators for floored division. In C++, you'd need to write a function using the above definitions.

Yet another way is **Euclidean division**, which can also be defined in terms of the builtin truncated division

```
auto const I = rT >= 0 ? 0 : (d > 0 ? 1 : -1);
auto const qE = qT - I;
auto const rE = rT + I * d;
assert(D == d * qE + rE);
assert(abs(rE) < abs(d));
assert(signum(rE) >= 0);
```

With Euclidean division, **the sign of the remainder is always non-negative**.

Comment: `assert(signum(rT) == signum(D));` can definitely fail.  Correct statement: `signum(rT)` is a member of the set { `0`, `signum(D)` }, or as an assert `assert(rT == 0 || signum(rT) == signum(D));`

Comment: @BenVoigt can you give a counterexample that would fire the assert?

Comment: Counterexample: `D = 10` and `d = 5`

Comment: Final bold statement in your answer is also wrong, should be "non-negative" rather than "positive"

Comment: @BenVoigt thank you for your suggested edits, I updated the answer. BTW, I wrote this answer using a home-grown library, which already incorporated your suggested edits, but which I forgot to add to this answer. See https://github.com/rhalbersma/xstd/blob/master/include/xstd/cstdlib.hpp

Answer (score 3):

The best solution ¹for a mathematician is to use Python.

C++ operator overloading has little to do with it. You can't overload operators for built-in types. What you want is simply a function. Of course you can use C++ templating to implement that function for all relevant types with just 1 piece of code.

The standard C library provides `fmod`, if I recall the name correctly, for floating point types.

For integers you can define a C++ function template that always returns non-negative remainder (corresponding to Euclidian division) as  ...

```
#include <stdlib.h>  // abs

template< class Integer >
auto mod( Integer a, Integer b )
    -> Integer
{
    Integer const r = a%b;
    return (r < 0? r + abs( b ) : r);
}
```

... and just write `mod(a, b)` instead of `a%b`.

Here the type `Integer` needs to be a signed integer type.

If you want the common math behavior where the sign of the remainder is the same as the sign of the divisor, then you can do e.g.

```
template< class Integer >
auto floor_div( Integer const a, Integer const b )
    -> Integer
{
    bool const a_is_negative = (a < 0);
    bool const b_is_negative = (b < 0);
    bool const change_sign  = (a_is_negative != b_is_negative);

    Integer const abs_b         = abs( b );
    Integer const abs_a_plus    = abs( a ) + (change_sign? abs_b - 1 : 0);

    Integer const quot = abs_a_plus / abs_b;
    return (change_sign? -quot : quot);
}

template< class Integer >
auto floor_mod( Integer const a, Integer const b )
    -> Integer
{ return a - b*floor_div( a, b ); }
```

… with the same constraint on `Integer`, that it's a signed type.

---

<sup>¹ Because Python's integer division rounds towards negative infinity.</sup>

Comment: your code seems to have the same bug as mine had before my edit. What if b is negative? :)

Comment: @Armen: thanks! but I'm too lazy to edit for just that... :-)

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: the `r` result has to make `a` = `r + b*(a/b)` true. no matter how the integer division is implemented the `b*something` is a multiple of `b`. this makes `r` a valid modulo result even if negative. you can add abs(`b`) to it and it will still be a valid modulo result.

Comment: The mathematically desired result is for the remainder to be zero or to have the same sign as the divisor (denominator). If the divisor is negative, then the remainder should be zero or negative. The C / C++ implementation results in the remainder being zero or having the same sign as the dividend (numerator).

Comment: @rcgldr: The accepted solution returns non-negative remainder for the case of negative divisor. And so does this answer, because the OP didn't specify a different result in this case, except that this answer produces that result with correct type using a C++ template, which the OP asked for. For the extra requirement, if it is one, one can change `r < 0? r + abs( b ) : r` to `(r == 0? 0 : (r < 0) != (b <0)? r + b : r)`; it can possibly be simplified, not sure.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - Take a look at [wiki modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). The original release of APL got it wrong, but this was corrected back in the 1960's. Classic languages like Cobol and Fortran and current languages like Matlab and Python have a correct implementation of modulo (some also include a remainder function that works like C / C++).

Comment: @rcgldr: However I'm not sure that Fortran has the math semantics, because C++ got the current (post C++11) rounding rule, rounding towards 0, from Fortran.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - For Fortran, modulo() is different than mod(). Look at the wiki article again. I don't know why C++ chose to use mod() instead of modulo(). I'll delete this comment later

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I hate % design for this too....

You may convert dividend to unsigned in a way like:

```
unsigned int offset = (-INT_MIN) - (-INT_MIN)%divider

result = (offset + dividend) % divider
```

where offset is closest to (-INT_MIN) multiple of module, so adding and subtracting it will not change modulo. Note that it have unsigned type and result will be integer. Unfortunately it cannot correctly convert values INT_MIN...(-offset-1) as they cause arifmetic overflow. But this method have advandage of only single additional arithmetic per operation (and no conditionals) when working with constant divider, so it is usable in DSP-like applications.

There's special case, where divider is 2<sup>N</sup> (integer power of two), for which modulo can be calculated using simple arithmetic and bitwise logic as

```
dividend&(divider-1)
```

for example

```
x mod 2 = x & 1
x mod 4 = x & 3
x mod 8 = x & 7
x mod 16 = x & 15
```

More common and less tricky way is to get modulo using this function (works only with positive divider):

```
int mod(int x, int y) {
    int r = x%y;
    return r<0?r+y:r;
}
```

This just correct result if it is negative.

Also you may trick:

(p%q + q)%q

It is very short but use two %-s which are commonly slow.

Answer (score 2):

I believe another solution to this problem would be use to variables of type long instead of int.

I was just working on some code where the % operator was returning a negative value which caused some issues (for generating uniform random variables on [0,1] you don't really want negative numbers :) ), but after switching the variables to type long, everything was running smoothly and the results matched the ones I was getting when running the same code in python (important for me as I wanted to be able to generate the same "random" numbers across several platforms.

Answer (score 2):

For a solution that uses no branches and only 1 mod, you can do the following

```
// Works for other sizes too,
// assuming you change 63 to the appropriate value
int64_t mod(int64_t x, int64_t div) {
  return (x % div) + (((x >> 63) ^ (div >> 63)) & div);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Warning: macro mod evaluates its arguments' side effects multiple times. */
#define mod(r,m) (((r) % (m)) + ((r)<0)?(m):0)
```

... or just get used to getting any representative for the equivalence class.

Comment: "Get used to getting any representative for the equivalence class"?! That's nonsense. If you wanted that you could just use the original "representative" `r`. The `%` operator has nothing to do with equivalence classes. It's the remainder operator and the remainder is well defined algebraically to be nonnegative and less than the divisor. Sadly C defined it the wrong way. Still, +1 for having one of the best answers.

Answer (score 0):

Example template for C++

```
template< class T >
T mod( T a, T b )
{
    T const r = a%b;
    return ((r!=0)&&((r^b)<0) ? r + b : r);
}
```

With this template, the returned remainder will be zero or have the same sign as the divisor (denominator) (the equivalent of rounding towards negative infinity), instead of the C++ behavior of the remainder being zero or having the same sign as the dividend (numerator) (the equivalent of rounding towards zero).

Answer (score -1):

```
define  MOD(a, b)       ((((a)%(b))+(b))%(b))
```

Comment: This works but defining it as a macro like this is ugly as hell. Here's a templated version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581594/how-do-i-do-modulus-in-c/2581867#2581867

Answer (score -1):

```
unsigned mod(int a, unsigned b) {
    return (a >= 0 ? a % b : b - (-a) % b);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution (for use when `mod` is positive) avoids taking negative divide or remainder operations all together:

```
int core_modulus(int val, int mod)
{
    if(val>=0)
        return val % mod;
    else
        return val + mod * ((mod - val - 1)/mod);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I would do:

```
((-1)+8) % 8
```

This adds the latter number to the first before doing the modulo giving 7 as desired. This should work for any number down to -8. For -9 add 2*8.

Comment: And for a variable whose value might be `-99999`?

Comment: Personally, I think this is a good answer. For example, if you only need to handle -1, you could add the modulus once.