# real modulo operator in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, modulo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to code a modulo (%) operator in C/C++/Obj-C that handles negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003232/how-to-code-a-modulo-operator-in-c-c-obj-c-that-handles-negative-numbers)

From what I understand (see [Modulo operator with negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594508/modulo-operator-with-negative-values) and [Modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)) C & C++ have a "remainder" operator `a % b` but no operator that actually does modular arithmetic when the LHS is negative.

Several languages do have such a function. Is it possible to build an efficient function in C/C++ (or is there no efficient way to do it on i686/x64 CPUs)?

Currently I use `(n * b + a) % b` where `n` is picked such that I'm fairly sure the entire LHS is non-negative, but inevitably code gets changed and bugs sometimes occur.

Note: in case it's not clear, by modular arithmetic I mean an operator such that `a + b % b = a % b` for all integers `a` and all positive integers `b`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003232/how-to-code-a-modulo-operator-in-c-c-obj-c-that-handles-negative-numbers

Comment: Are you working with integers? Otherwise I would recommend `std::fmod`.

Comment: Integers, yes. Mostly as array indices.

Comment: Im really late to the party (7 years too late), but is this: `(a % b + b) % b` maybe what you are looking for?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no simple way to do it, however it is more efficient if you create a two-line solution, and spare a multiplication plus determining `n`.

```
inline int modulo(int a, int b) {
  const int result = a % b;
  return result >= 0 ? result : result + b;
}
```

Also, if you need to work correctly for negative `b` numbers as well, add to the beginning:

```
          if(b < 0) return modulo(-a, -b);
```

Comment: "There's no simple way to do it"...  Really?  Your solution looks pretty simple to me. +1

Comment: Wow, that was quick! I'll test performance later, but unless the jump is significant it's probably not going to be much slower than what I use ATM.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a function like the one above, but using `inline int modulo(int a, int b) {}` (just as if the operator existed in C++). Personnally I don't use negative numbers often, and still think you should keep `%` whenever your code doesn't use negative numbers.

Comment: I added the inline suggestion to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is code gets changed, and what was once non-negative sometimes ends up being negative. I might use % along with an assert in places though (I don't care about debug-mode performance so much).

Comment: @dhardy what do you mean the code gets changed? The cases I was talking about are for example array indexes (that are never <0), or incremental counters.

Comment: I mean new features imply old stuff gets changed, not always in a way that gives every little detail of that change the attention it deserves. Have a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/openmalaria/source/detail?r=2449) then come help look for more bugs if you really want to know.