# Caesar cipher decryption in C++

Tags: c++, encryption, caesar-cipher

I can not seem to figure out why only certain letters in my decryption are not working. I am trying to decrypt the letters kddkmu with a key of 10. It is suppose to come out to attack but every time I run the code it comes out to aZZack. I believe the problem has something to do with my modulus operation but no matter what I do I cant figure out the problem.

```
int key = 10;
ciphertext = "kddkmu";
plaintext = shift_decrypt(ciphertext, key);

cout << "2. Decryption of the ciphertext: " << ciphertext << endl;

cout << "   Key: " << key << endl;

cout << "   Plaintext; " << plaintext << endl << endl;
```

with

```
string shift_decrypt(string p, int a)
{
    string dtext = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < p.length(); i++)
    {
        dtext += char(int(p[i] - a - 97) % 26 + 97);
    }

    return dtext;
}
```

I am not getting any errors its just decrypting the dd as ZZ for some odd reason

Comment: in c++, modulus of a negative will be negative

Comment: I've already provided the hints and links in your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58189369/1820553).

Comment: Break down the math and inspect step by step. Step 1: Have lots of fun. Step 2 `int shifted = ch - a -97;` Print it out and make sure it is correct  Step 3: `int modded = shifted % 26;` Again, print and check. Step 4: `int shifted_back = modded + 97;`  Print and check. Then make sure the message encrypted correctly.

Comment: What's significant about 97?  Do you mean `'a'`?  If so, then use `'a`' instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest subtraction with modulus (remainder) operator.

We know that `(X * 26) % 26 == 0` for all X.
So, we can add an extra 26 with no cost.
To subtract, we can add (26 - Y) to the value and still have a positive value.

Step by step:
1) Shift the character into the range of `0 - 25`, inclusive:
`int value = letter - 'a';`

2) Remove the Caesar offset by "subtracting" the key:
`value = (value + 26 - key) % 26;`

3) Shift the value to the range `a` to `z`:
`char decrypted_letter = value + 'a';`

Comment: actually you should use `x + 26* k = x mod 26`. `26` is already `0` in modulus `26`.