# Are there any normal mathematical quotient and remainder for `int` somewhere in C++?

Tags: c++, std, modular-arithmetic

Remainder is always positive, for example,

```
remainder(-1, 7) == 6
```

not `-1`

And quotient should be rounded towards minus infinity, not towards zero, for example,

```
quotient(-1, 7) == -1
```

not `0`.

Are there such functions somewhere in stdlib?

Comment: You can massage the remainder with `rem = (rem + divisor) % divisor` to make it be positive. Not sure there's a similarly concise adjustment for quotient.

Comment: Related: [Fastest way to get a positive modulo in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997165/fastest-way-to-get-a-positive-modulo-in-c-c)

Comment: You can use the `div` function https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_div.htm and make the adjustments on your own.

Comment: @Nathan Pierson  `rem = (rem + divisor) % divisor` risks overflow with `rem + divisor`.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any normal mathematical quotient and remainder for `int` somewhere in C++?

The `%` is the *remainder* operator, but we can use it to nearly get us there.

To achieve the [Euclidean modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division#Division_theorem)

```
 7 modulo  3 -->  1  
 7 modulo -3 -->  1  
-7 modulo  3 -->  2  
-7 modulo -3 -->  2
```

Use

```
int modulo_Euclidean(int a, int b) {
  int m = a % b;
  if (m < 0) {
    // m += (b < 0) ? -b : b; // avoid this form: it is UB when b == INT_MIN
    m = (b < 0) ? m - b : m + b;
  }
  return m;
}
```

See also [Fastest way to get a positive modulo in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57544473/2410359) which covers various pitfalls.

Comment: Might be worth linking the question where you [previously posted this as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57544473/11082165) for its discussion about UB risks.

Answer (score 1):

you can do `(num1 % num2 + num2) % num2` to get the remainder when you divide `num1` by `num2` and `floor(1.0 * num1 / num2)` to get a rounded down quotient. (`floor` is found in the `cmath` library)

Comment: ah, i forgot about that part

Comment: @NathanOliver fixed

Comment: Using floating point can lose precision, especially if using 64-bit integers.