# explicit MOD in C?

Tags: c, modulo

Ok So I know and understand the difference between MOD and REM. I also am aware that C's % operation is a REM operation. I wanted to know, and could not find online, if there is some C library or function for an explicit MOD.

Specifically, I'd like `(-1)%4 == 3` to be true. In C `(-1)%4 = -1` since it is a remainder. And preferably I'd like to avoid using absolute values and even better would be to utilize some built in function that I can't seem to find.

Any advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: See [How to code a modulo (%) operator in C/C++/Obj-C that handles negative numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003232/how-to-code-a-modulo-operator-in-c-c-obj-c-that-handles-negative-numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option I can think of is to compute:

```
((-1 % 4) + 4 ) % 4
```

Here you may replace `-1` with any value and you will get `MOD` not `REM`.

Answer (score 0):

Just do,

```
int mod(int a, int b)
{
    int res = a % b;
    return(res < 0 ? (res + b) : res);
}
```

Every negative `res` content after `MOD` operation is added to `b` to get modulus of `a` & `b`.

Comment: one line: `return (a < 0 ? (a % b + b) : (a % b));`

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to do what you expect is:

```
((a % b) + b ) % b
```

It works because `(a % b)` is a number in ]-b; b[ so `(a % b) + b` is positive (in ]0; 2 * b[) and adding `b` did not changed the mod.