# Why is a modulo operation returning an unexpected value

Tags: c, gcc, modulo

Why is the following code printing `255`?

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  uint8_t i = 0;
  i = (i - 1) % 16;
  printf("i: %d\n", i);
  return 0;
}
```

I assumed `15`, although `i - 1` evaluates to an integer.

Comment: uint - unsigned int, 0-1 becomes MAX_INT

Comment: @MarcB: `0 - 1` is `-1`. `MAX_INT` is `>= 32767`.

Comment: @olaf: it's an unsigned int

Comment: You take an unsigned int, set it to 0 and then take one away.  Great.

Comment: @MarcB: The first operand (of type `uint8_t`) is converted to `int` due to _integer promotions_. It might be converted to `unsigned int`, but only if `int` type does not cover all values of `uint8_t`, which is possible, but very unlikely.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski `int` is at least 16-bit and `uint8_t` is exactly 8, so impossible actually.

Comment: @MarcB: It is not. Please read my answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because of [integer promotions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1) in the C standard. Briefly: any type "smaller" than `int` is converted to `int` before usage. You cannot avoid this in general.

**So what goes on:** `i` is promoted to `int`. The expression is evaluated as `int` (the constants you use are `int`, too). The modulus is `-1`. This is then converted to `uint8_t`: `255` by the assignment.

For `printf` then `i` is integer-promoted to `int` (again): `(int)255`. However, this does no harm.

Note that in C89, for `a < 0`, `a % b` is not necessarily negative. It was implementation-defined and could have been `15`. However, since C99, `-1 % 16` is guaranteed to be `-1` as the division has to yield the *algebraic quotient*.

---

If you want to make sure the modulus gives a positive result, you have to evaluate the whole expression `unsigned` by casting `i`:

```
i = ((unsigned)i - 1) % 16;
```

**Recommendation:** Enable compiler warnings. At least the conversion for the assignment should give a truncation warning.

Comment: It's only implementation-defined in C89/C90. The linked C11 standard paragraph even defines it in the second sentence and the UB stuff isn't relevant here.

Comment: Then read the first sentence including the footnote too. Your second example (specifically `a / 16 == -1`) doesn't satisfy it. The C99 rationale (6.5.5 on page 67, 7.20.6 on 164 and 165) are also a helpful resource.

Comment: Regarding the truncation warning, `((unsigned)i - 1) % 16` is guaranteed to be in the range 0 through 15, so there *should* be no warning for assigning it to a `uint8_t` because the value cannot be out of range.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: The truncation is due to assigning a larger type to a smaller one, not about the outcome of the RHS. The compiler cannot detect all situations the expression is within valid range. Here, truncation _does_ occur, because `(int)(uint8_t)(int)-1` in fact is a truncation truncated, as it does not yield the original value anymore. Things would have been different with `int8_t`.

Comment: The remainder/division I read again. Yes, my bad, I did not honour the "algebraic division" correctly (had to look that up in a dict first). It is more important than I first thought. Point taken.

Comment: @cremno: Second point taken. I did not pay proper attention to the _algebraic quotient_ part. Somehow the old C90 definition shadowed that. Agree, that's quite an important difference.

Comment: Not all constants are of type `int`. All *unsuffixed* constants whose values are in the range `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX` are of type `int`. (Of course the constants `0`, `1`, and `16` in the OP's code qualify, and are of type `int`.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: Ok, got it (sorry, that was a bit ago). I think I can restrict to the constants in the question, which are definitively `int`.

Answer (score 13):

This is because `-1 % n` would return `-1` and NOT `n - 1` <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4003232/1492578)</sup>. Since `i` in this case is unsigned 8 bit int, it becomes 255.

<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4003232/1492578)</sup> [See this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4003232/1492578) on how modulo for negative integers works in C/C++.

Comment: That's true, but the OP is apparently expecting `uint8_t` to behave as *8-bit unsigned* type throughout the process of evaluation and produce `255` instead of `-1` *before* calculating the modulo. The reason `uint8_t` does not behave that way is that it is promoted to `int` first.

Comment: Downvoting because this doesn't explain why it's `-1 % n` instead of `255 % n` (integer promotion rules, see Olaf's more complete answer).

Answer (score 2):

This works (displays 15) with Microsoft C compiler (no stdint.h, so I used a typedef):

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

int main(void) {
    uint8_t i = 0;
    i = (uint8_t)(i - 1) % 16;
    printf("i: %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

The reason for the 255 is because (i - 1) is promoted to integer, and the integer division used for % in C rounds towards zero instead of negative infinity (rounding towards negative infinity is the way it's done in math, science, and other programming languages). So for C % is zero or has the same sign as the dividend (in this case -1%16 == -1), while in math modulo is zero or has the same sign as the divisor.