# How I can solve C++ output negative numbers when using modulo?

Tags: c++, modulo

In a code written by me, I have used both below functions to calculate mod of displayed negative number.

```
fmod(-10,11)
(-10, 11)
```

Though the **[correct answer is 1](https://miniwebtool.com/modulo-calculator/?number1=-10&number2=11)**. It always displays the **answer -10 in c++**. How I can solve it?

Comment: [How to code a modulo (%) operator in C/C++/Obj-C that handles negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4003232/995714),

Comment: "the correct answer is 1" thats a matter of convention, a different convention says that the correct answer is `-10`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From cppreference.com:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod)

> `double fmod (double numer, double denom);`
>   The floating-point remainder of the division operation `x/y` calculated by this function is exactly the value `x - n*y`, where `n` is `x/y` with its fractional part truncated.
>   The returned value has the same sign as `x` and is less than `y` in magnitude.

In your case it is `-10 - (-10)/11 * 11 = -10 - 0 * 11 = -10`, which is correct for that implementation of `fmod`. If you need another answer, you should implement your own version, as `modulo` is defined in different ways for negative numbers.

Comment: cplusplus.com **is not** "C++ Reference", due to multiple mistakes inside it. cppreference.com is, since it, at least tries to follow C++ standard as closely, as possible.

Comment: My bad, took a look at the tab name, where it says "fmod - C++ Reference".

Comment: Due to the reasons mentioned: you should avoid linking new users to a site with potential mistakes, instead of an actual C++ reference.

Comment: usually I am reluctant to discredit the work of many with good intentions, but I can confirm, it happened just too often that I was mislead by wrong/incomplete information, till now I never had such experience on cppreference